# App displaying the wrong number of answers

Tags: bug, android-app

The Android app is displaying the wrong number of answers to one of my questions, even after several refreshes and force closing/reopening the app.

The answers are both several hours old (>7) <sub><sup>so don't say caching</sup></sub>. Also, it is worth noting that this question was put on hold. Does that affect this number from updating? EDIT: It was closed just before I took this screenshot, so I don't think that is part of the problem.

[image: wrong number of answers]

App 1.0.24 running on HTC One X with Android 4.1.1

Comment: Could you post a link to the question?

Comment: @Doorknob http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104371/42915

Comment: [status-norepro]; I see "2 answers." Galaxy S4, app 1.0.24, Android 4.3.

Comment: I can't repo it right this second. But I can confirm it has happened to me on more than one occasion. Probably caching...

Comment: Yeah, it's probably caching. That would explain why nobody else could repro it. (Also, it's *always* caching. :-P)

Comment: @Doorknob Seems odd that it updates the content but not the number.

Comment: I see this too. The "number of answers" does not update when an answer is posted and you simply _refresh_ (drag down and release) to view the new answer. Everything is updated, apart from the "number of answers" at the top of the screen. However, if I navigate to an entirely different question, and back again - which results in a complete screen redraw then the correct "number of answers" is shown. This is reproducible every time a new answer is posted when you have the question open (of course you can't see that there is a new answer unless you manually refresh).

Comment: ...Like the screenshot above, that clearly shows 2 answers, but it only states "1 ANSWER", I have a screenshot that states "0 ANSWERS" when there is 1 answer shown, even after refreshing (drag and release). Navigating away to another page and back again appears to resolve the issue. App 1.0.31 running on Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.2

Comment: This issue still exists in version 1.0.35 of the Android App. However, I have just realised that by rotating the screen to landscape and back to portrait does in fact redraw the entire screen and the answer count gets refreshed! (Drag down and release does not refresh this.)

Comment: This issue cannot be reproduced anymore, since current app shows both question and answers on same thread, removing the tabs for "question" and "answers".