# Does the section showing the revision date in the Android app have any action associated?

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

[image: IMG:]

As can be seen in the screenshot, the area showing the revision date glows blue when touched. Does it have any action associated, or is it a dummy button? If nothing is supposed to happen when you tap it, then the glowing is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrew T. mentioned, we used to have the post interaction buttons (which are now the line above the area in question in your screenshot) exist after tapping on that field. That hasn't been the case for a long time, and I thought I removed the interaction with that section but it turns out I edited the section in one of the two XML files it exists in, oops!

As of version 1.0.83, coming out later today, this is fixed. Hopefully I'll make it clickable again soon to go to a revision history view (showing actual diffs on revisions is... painful)

Comment: Let me trawl through your recent posts to see if we are getting anything nice and shiny with this version! :)

Comment: @muru everything I've marked [status-completed] in the last few weeks will be in the next big update, right now it's all just on the beta tier. Search link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswered%20%5bstatus-completed%5d%20%5bandroid-app%5d%20is%3aquestion

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's doing nothing now, since it's a remnant from long time ago when actions such as "Favorite, Edit, Share" was put inside an overflow menu on the revision info. (compare to below screenshot)

[image: old app!]

<sup>(Image taken from [this question on MSE by Austin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226244/app-displaying-the-wrong-number-of-answers))</sup>

Comment: That's likely. Though I keep hoping that this is SE teasing us: "You can view revisions here any time now.. Soon..."

Comment: Ooh, I very much hope that we can [see revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228440/241919) directly from app :)